# why did I get error in sed command?

Tags: shell, sed

```
$ ls | sed -n "/c/{/s/r/ssss/;p}"
```

When running this line in terminal, I got:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'

What's wrong?

Comment: It's not escaped properly, try: `ls | sed -n "/c\/{\/s/r\/ssss\/;p\}"`

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do, please.  I gave an answer, then realized there were other possibilities for what you're trying to do.

Comment: suggestions: 1) [avoid parsing ls output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) 2) add sample input and expected output for clarity..

Answer (score 2):

I think there's one too many `/` characters in there.

You probably need:

```
ls | sed -n "/c/{ s/r/ssss/;p;}"
```

This looks for lines from `ls` containing a `c`, and replaces the first `r` with `ssss` and prints the result.

It works with the Mac (BSD) version of `sed` and the GNU version too.  The GNU version is OK without the semicolon after the `p` but the Mac version is not.

However, there could be other ways to interpret what you're trying to do, and that might lead to a different command line.  If you're trying to find a line containing a `c` and an `s` and replace the whole line with `ssss` (and maybe some other characters — it isn't clear what you've aiming for), then you'd have to do more work, in both GNU and Mac/BSD versions of `sed`.

Comment: what I need is the command you posted 'ls | sed -n "/c/{ s/r/ssss/;p;}"', I am using git bash, and it seems that semicolon is required after the letter p.